# Wordpress: Using one plugin file's function in another plugin's file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have two plugins that work together (one is an add-on of sorts). In the "main" plugin, I have a js function in  a file located like so:

```
wp-plugins/main-plugin-name/js/main-js.js
```

If my secondary plugin, I have another .js file located like so:

```
wp-plugins/secondary-plugin-name/js/sec-js.js
```

In this second plugin's .js file, I want to use a function located in the first .js file. Basically I want the function to be globally available to both plugins.

I have already registered and enqueued the first .js script using the main plugin, but I can't seem to get the secondary plugin to find the function from the first, and use it.

In first plugin's main function file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_script');
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_script');
function custom_enqueue_script() {
wp_register_script( '123-script-name', $plugin_url.'js/123-script-name.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( '123-script-name' );
}
```

Within that file, there is a function:

```
function 789_function() {
alert('this function ran!');
}
```

In the second plugin's .js file, I want to use that function, which seems like I should be able to since that file is already enqueued, but throws an uncaught reference error instead when the function is called.

Comment: Of course it's possible. The different files are irrelevant. What matters is scope and possibly order of loading depending on when and where the function is called. . Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function name `789_function` looks funky. Try renaming it:

```
function testName() {
    alert('this is a function ran!')
}
```

**Script 2**

```
testName();
```

My best guess is wordpress does some quirky stuff because they don't want you modifying their codebase.

## Concept

As long as the first script is loaded *before* the second script, the second script should be able to utilize it just fine.

**first.js**

```
var codeStuff = "This is code in the first script! :D";
```

**second.js**

```
console.log(codeStuff);
```

**Output**

```
"This is code in the first script! :D"
```

--

**Page**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="first.js"></script>
<script src="second.js"></script>
<body>
<p>My name is Eckstein and I'm awesome.</p>
</body>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is actually helpful because it's what I would expect to happen and it's good to know I'm not wrong. Perhaps I need to play with priorities, that may be the issue...

Comment: I just appended to my answer with your code, have a looksie and see if that helps.